# jQuery Click Event Reloads Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event

I'm am attempting to add a new row to a table by clicking an add row button. However, clicking the add row button simply refreshes the page.

I have tried multiple ways to stop this such as `preventDefualt` and `return false`, all to no avail.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    $('#btn-add-item').on('click'),
      function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("works");
        return false;
      }

  });

</script>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-add-item"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add item</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close the `click` handler properly, check the location of end parenthesis.

Below is the snippet with correct format:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    $('#btn-add-item').on('click', // <-- removing end paranthesis after "click" event will close the function
      function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("works");
        return false;
      }); // <-- adding end paranthesis here

  });
</script>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-add-item"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add item</button>
```